# Azure Pipeline run tasks based on the designated android flavor

Tags: android, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that ones running perfectly when my application wasn't flavored.
it was building, signing and releasing the application to the firebase distribution.

Now I have the application flavored and I want on each push to development to release the app whether on com.example_flavor1 or com.example_flavor2

the gradle task and the firebase app id should change according to the flavor but i'm not knowing how to do so, can you help please

Here's my pipeline

```
trigger:
- development

variables:
- group: 'Variables'


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build & Archive
  jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    vmImage: $(vmImage)  
  steps: 
  - task: Gradle@2
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: ''
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: false
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
      tasks: 'assembleRelease --stacktrace'
  
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    displayName: Retrieving the Keystore
    inputs:
      secureFile: 'keystore.keystore'

  - task: AndroidSigning@3
    displayName: Signing the Release 2
    inputs:
      apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
      apksign: true
      apksignerKeystoreFile: 'keystore.keystore'
      apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(KeyStorePassword)'
      apksignerKeystoreAlias: '$(KeyAlias)'
      apksignerKeyPassword: '$(KeyPassword)'
      apksignerArguments: --out $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Build.BuildID)-release.apk
      zipalign: false

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Archive APKs 
    inputs:
      contents: '**/*.apk'
      targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/apk'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Archive AABs 
    inputs:
      contents: '**/*.aab'
      targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/aab'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish build artifacts
    inputs: 
      pathToPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: '$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Build.BuildID)'

- stage: Publish
  displayName: Publish
 condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment:
displayName: Firebase Tools install and deploy
pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImage)
environment: Dev
strategy:
  runOnce:
    deploy:
      steps:            
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '10.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'

      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          artifactName: '$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Build.BuildID)'
          downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

      - script: |
          cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)
          npm install -g firebase-tools
          firebase appdistribution:distribute $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Build.BuildID)/apk/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Build.BuildID)-release.apk --project $(firebase-project-id) --app $(firebase-android-app-id) --token $(firebase-token) --testers "$(firebase-testers-emails)" --groups "$(firebase-testers-groups)" --release-notes "$(release-notes)" --debug
        displayName: 'npm install and distribute'
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted#what-is-a-parallel-job) in Azure Devops to support an arbitrary number of Gradle flavors an Android app. And use [Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) to define reusable content, logic, and parameters. For example:

```
jobs:
  - job: A
    variables:
      - group: "A"
    steps:
      - template: build.yml

  - job: B
    variables:
      - group: "B"
    steps:
      - template: build.yml
```

Here is a simple example you may refer to:

https://github.com/seanKenkeremath/AzureDevopsAndroidFlavorsExample